# How to enable the full screen mode for Kali Linux on Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: kali-linux, display, display-settings, hyper-v

I have successfully installed Kali Linux on Hyper-V. The problem is that the OS doesn't take the whole screen. It takes only part of it. How to make Kali Linux run on full screen (physical)?

[image]

Comment: Install Linux Integration Services

Answer (score 6):

In `/etc/default/grub` change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet”` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:your_resolution″` for me it was `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920×1080″`. Save file then run `sudo update-grub` and `restart`.

Answer (score 6):

If this doesn't work on Hyper-v (You will see this message briefly on during boot process "hyperv_fb screen option is invalid"

Run the following command in Powershell as administrator on Windows host:

```
*set-vmvideo -vmname <NameOfVM> -horizontalresolution:2560  -verticalresolution:1440 -resolutiontype single*
```

Comment: Thanks for that! For 4K:
Set-VMVideo -VMName myVM -HorizontalResolution:3840 -VerticalResolution:2160 -ResolutionType Single - For some reason, I cannot scale to 2x...

Comment: This is THE answer! Changing `/etc/default/grub` doesn't help on Kali-2021.3, but `set-vmvideo -vmname NameOfVM -horizontalresolution:1920 -verticalresolution:1200 -resolutiontype single` does

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with this:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Edit:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet”
```

Change to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920×1080"
```

Finally:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then

```
sudo reboot
```